# Using Firefox XUL, is is possible to eliminate the listbox border with a style?

Tags: listbox, xul

I have the following XUL fragment, which works fine, but puts a 1 pixel border around the entire listbox.  I've tried a number of CSS styles, but cannot eliminate the border.

Any ideas?

```
<listbox>
 <listhead>
  <listheader id="adj_lh_1" label = "one"/>
  <listheader id="adj_lh_2" label = "two"/>
 </listhead>
  <listcols>
   <listcol flex="1" />
   <listcol flex="1" />
  </listcols>
 <listitem>
  <listcell id="adj_li_1"  label="data one" />
  <listcell id="adj_li_1"  label="data two" />
 </listitem>
</listbox>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply the "-moz-appearance: none;" style rule in your css.

Eg.:

> listbox {
>
> -moz-appearance: none;
>
> -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
>
> -moz-border-top-colors: none;
>
> -moz-border-left-colors: none;
>
> -moz-border-right-colors: none;
>
> border: none;
>
> }

Comment: That changes it, but does not eliminate it

Comment: No, but after you have added that style you can then apply whatever border settings you want.

Comment: Forgot to add that you might need to use :
-moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
 -moz-border-top-colors: none;
 -moz-border-left-colors: none;
 -moz-border-right-colors: none;
aswell.

Comment: border color none didn't work, but changing the border colors to white, the same as by background made them "disappear".  Can you edit your answer, adding the additional css lines, then I'll accept it.

Comment: border color none is not enough, you have to use the specific "-moz" ones 1 for each side 4 in total. Will edit the answer :)